# Unity 2D - Limbo like character movement

Tags: unity-game-engine, box2d

AFAIK Limbo uses Box2D.
First of all, could someone please explain how is the character set up? Does it use rigidbody with colliders? If so what type of colliders and how are they placed?

Secondly: As I see the character always moves the same distance in the same amount of time, ignoring slopes, etc. Is that correct?

And finally (at least for now :) ): How does the character determines whether it's standing on the ground or not? Does it use raycast?

Thanks!

Comment: In the unity standard assets there are a few different character setups.  For each of them you can clone the prefab into your scene, and inspect the objects and components they comprised of.  All the way down to the logic used in the scripts.

Comment: Thats's good for a simple platformer, but it's nothing like Limbo. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About colliders, usually one (or a low number) of simple colliders (boxes or spheres, circles in 2D) are enough to give a proper collision detection for a character (in unity, you would have to use colliders+rigidbody2D to make that movement)

Secondly, it seems that the values of physics are tweak so things like slopes doesn't really affect players movement, and movement script may be placed so horizontal force (or speed) is constant (not exactly constant really, but close)

For determine if character is grounded, the easiest (and i think more efficient) way is to use [OnCollisionEnter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) and [OnCollisionExit](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionExit.html) to change a boolean value (so it is true when grounded and false if not). Avoid using raycasting, as it is expensive, and it's not a good idea to do it per frame (also, more complex to implement)

I'm not 100% sure on how is the movement in Limbo made, but my best guesses are these, correctly testing and tuning the values you can get almost any 2D movement with some basic scripting with rigidbody & collider